# Wiener filter with no WSS process

Tags: image-processing, filters, discrete-signals, signal-analysis

I'm trying to learn something more about Wiener Filters and I can't find anywhere what happens when I feed a Wiener Filter with a non WSS process. Could anyone give me an explanation or any book (specifically, which chapter/s) that explains that?

Thanks!

WSS: Wide Sense Stationary

Comment: As you know, the Wiener filter is designed with respect to a given signal and noise statistics and will have the **optimal** performance. And as such it is a **fixed** filter for that particular case. If the input statistics changes during filtering, (that violating the WSS assumption) then either you should redesign your filter on the fly as an update process, or more appropriately enter to the amazing world of **Adaptive Filtering** . You shall begin with the Haykin's classical book "Adaptive Filter Theory" and also Widrow's book is highly recommended

Comment: I'm reading Haykin's book and it's really nice, but I can't find the answer to my question. I mean, if the input of the filter (u(0), u(1), ...) is a non WSS process, what do I do? Of course I have to redesign the filter, but how? What conditions do I have to keep in mind? The filter model I'm using is from Haykin (I can't post an image here), in page 109 in the 5th edition

Comment: so you haven't read yet the chapter on **LMS** adaptive filters?

Comment: Of course I did! I also made a summary of that chapter. I did it in Spanish, but if you need it I can give it to you :). I read until chapter 10 because I didn't study yet Kalman filters.

Comment: When the input process is not WSS, then your filter should **adapt** to its input's statistical characterisation, a property called as **tracking**. Those filters calles as LMS (being the simplest) will adopt their filter coefficients according to input characterisaiton and hence will try to provide optimal performance even when the input is not WSS. Of course tracking is not a perfect process and errors will be larger during.

Comment: You are better than me! I haven't read its full chapters ever. So what's your question? if input is not WSS, your filter should be **adaptive**. It's why called as an adaptive filter ?

Comment: You can also use Kalman filters. But that's a more difficult approach.

Comment: I didn't study Kalman filters yet, so I can't use that. I think that you know much more than me about this! Don't be so humble!! haha. OK, I will study more about adaptive filters and tracking. Thanks!

Comment: Fat, can you please tell me exactly in which chapter can I read about this? Thanks

Comment: I mean, I found the adaptive filter (I used an MIT lesson) but everything is in the air, I couldn't find any nice example like: "You have this signal as the input that is not WSS because this, and you use this filter because of this".